# Is it possible to show the text inside <h3> over the inline image, without using <span> and images in background?

Tags: css, xhtml

Is it possible to show the text inside `<h3>` over the image, without using `<span>` and images in background?

**HTML**

```
<h3>sample caption 1<img alt="" src="banner4.jpg" /></h3>
```

**CSS**

```
h3{ }
h3 img { }
```

Comment: I can't think of a good way to do it. I guess you could have a play with z-index's. I would recommend setting the image as a background as your best option.

Comment: Yeah. Probably impossible without a painful level of hackery.  Why can't you use spans?

Comment: Hmm, well they designed it so that objects don't overlap with inline text, so you'd kind of be like defying the laws of gravity. Why not put the image outside the header and have the header overlap on top of the image?

Answer (score 0):

To have a img tag inside of a h3 tag is bad practice.

what you could do is:

```
<div>
<h3>sample caption 1</h3>
<img src="banner4.jpg" alt="banner" />
</div>
```

and then alter the position or padding and margin to maneuver the text over the image, maybe put a z-index to ensure it shows the text on top.

```
img{z-index:10;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;}
h3{z-index:20;}
div{position:relative;}
```

The easiest way though is to use a background image on the h3.

Comment: "To have a tag inside of a tag is bad practice." Really? Because I believe HTML is all tags inside of tags.

Comment: But I have Multiple items on same page, I just given one for example.

Comment: @animuson i realized that having the <> on the img and h3 made them invisible on the page :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo

http://jsbin.com/ozobo5

Comment: If you add z-index to that will it work? Text underneath an image is not very helpful.

Comment: @animuson: No, it won't work. `z-index: -1` on the image *kinda works*, but it's no good on a real page, because the image will end up underneath elements it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think it's possible to do it how you asked in the question.

And believe me, *I tried*.

There's just no way to style that text without an element enclosing it. The only hope I had was the `:first-line` pseudo-element, but that [didn't help](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/x9Bq2/) either.

It's pretty easy to do it in [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vqaFf/) though, which is completely different to the question you asked in the first place:

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/vqaFf/1/